# How to have VS Code format HTML code adding white line space when hit enter

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

What should I change in VS Code so that when I create a label and then hit the enter key, the editor automatically creates a blank line for me and adds tab stops like in the following image?

https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/languages/html/auto-close1.gif

I have this settings in my editor settings.json:

```js
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
"editor.autoSurround": "brackets",
```

Currently what I need to do is hit the enter key twice and then manually tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by copying all the default options from the settings.json file and comparing with the ones I already have set. The value to change was:

```json
"editor.autoIndent": "keep",
```

and it should be:

```json
"editor.autoIndent": "full",
```